# Pythonで、libjpegをインストールする方法が分かりません。

Tags: python, 機械学習

エラーは以下のようになっています。

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-bc99f0644372> in <module>()
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 
----> 4 people=fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=20,resize=0.7)
      5 image_shape=people.images[0].shape
      6 

~\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\lfw.py in fetch_lfw_people(data_home, funneled, resize, min_faces_per_person, color, slice_, download_if_missing)
    332     faces, target, target_names = load_func(
    333         data_folder_path, resize=resize,
--> 334         min_faces_per_person=min_faces_per_person, color=color, slice_=slice_)
    335 
    336     # pack the results as a Bunch instance

~\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    560 
    561     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 562         return self._cached_call(args, kwargs)[0]
    563 
    564     def __reduce__(self):

~\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py in _cached_call(self, args, kwargs)
    508                           'directory %s'
    509                         % (name, argument_hash, output_dir))
--> 510             out, metadata = self.call(*args, **kwargs)
    511             if self.mmap_mode is not None:
    512                 # Memmap the output at the first call to be consistent with

~\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py in call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    742         if self._verbose > 0:
    743             print(format_call(self.func, args, kwargs))
--> 744         output = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    745         self._persist_output(output, output_dir)
    746         duration = time.time() - start_time

~\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\lfw.py in _fetch_lfw_people(data_folder_path, slice_, color, resize, min_faces_per_person)
    233     target = np.searchsorted(target_names, person_names)
    234 
--> 235     faces = _load_imgs(file_paths, slice_, color, resize)
    236 
    237     # shuffle the faces with a deterministic RNG scheme to avoid having

~\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\lfw.py in _load_imgs(file_paths, slice_, color, resize)
    186             raise RuntimeError("Failed to read the image file %s, "
    187                                "Please make sure that libjpeg is installed"
--> 188                                % file_path)
    189 
    190         face = np.asarray(img[slice_], dtype=np.float32)

RuntimeError: Failed to read the image file C:\Users\scikit_learn_data\lfw_home\lfw_funneled\Gloria_Macapagal_Arroyo\Gloria_Macapagal_Arroyo_0024.jpg, Please make sure that libjpeg is installed
```

Comment: 質問文とエラー文やコードなどの境目を分かりやすくするために、コードをハイライトしました。編集中にコードを選択して`{}`ボタンを選択しても同じことが出来ますのでお試しください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。次回からは見やすさに気を付けたいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C:\` という表記からして環境はWindowsでしょうか。

本家SOの同様の質問によると、 `libjpeg` を必要とするパッケージについて、カリフォルニア大学アーバイン校が配布しているWindows向け非公式ビルドをインストールするという手があるようです。
[python - Installing pillow on windows fails to find libjpeg - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672530/installing-pillow-on-windows-fails-to-find-libjpeg)

[Python Extension Packages for Windows - Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: Python Extension Packages for Windows - Christoph Gohlkeのうち、どれをインストールすれば良いかよくわかりませんでした。お手数おかけして申し訳ありませんが、教えていただけますでしょうか。よろしくお願いします<m(__)m>

Comment: 現在どのパッケージを使っているのでしょうか？ 機械学習タグが付いているので、それ関連だと推測出来ますが、実際に使用しているパッケージ次第となります。また、質問文に記載されているエラーメッセージ以外にもスタックトレースが出力されていると思うので、そちらも確認すると実際にエラーを吐いているパッケージが分かるかと存じます。

Comment: Anacondaを使っています。

Comment: Anacondaはパッケージ（モジュール、ライブラリ）ではなく、環境構築用のプラットフォームのようなものです。今回はmatplotlib及びsklearnをお使い（で、この周辺からエラーが発生している）のようですので、これらをインストールしてご確認してみてください。

Comment: 返信遅れて申し訳ありません。無事エラーを解決することができました。本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: 無事解決したようでなによりです。✓（解決としてマーク）をクリックし、この質問を完了させてください。